# Check if array values is a substring of a string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to know if there's a function that can search through array and return if it's value is a substring of a string.

It would be something like this in sql. `LIKE '%arr.value%'`

```
let arr = ['welcome', 'answer', 'question']
let str = 'welcome001'
```

Comment: Do you want to find out whether any of the array (```arr```) values has the string matching with the ```str```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `String.prototype.includes()` and `Array.prototype.find()` to find your required string

```js
    let arr = ['welcome', 'answer', 'question']
    let str = 'welcome001';
    const result = arr.find(item => str.includes(item));
    
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm looking for. Will accept this answer after the timer.

Comment: Glad to help you